# Can't access 8000 port after install Kong

Tags: api, docker, gateway, kong

Installed Kong with docker by official guide. Then add an API:

```
curl -i -X POST \
  --url http://1.2.3.4:8001/apis/ \
  --data 'name=test-api' \
  --data 'hosts=1.2.3.4' \
  --data 'upstream_url=http://1.2.3.4:3000'
```

Check API:

```
curl -i -X GET \
  --url http://1.2.3.4:8001/apis/

{
  "total": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "created_at": 1530076151932,
      "strip_uri": true,
      "id": "ab2ea516-ef44-4f00-a55f-4ed8bb0b69a0",
      "hosts": [
        "1.2.3.4"
      ],
      "name": "test-api",
      "http_if_terminated": false,
      "https_only": false,
      "retries": 5,
      "preserve_host": false,
      "upstream_connect_timeout": 60000,
      "upstream_read_timeout": 60000,
      "upstream_send_timeout": 60000,
      "upstream_url": "http://1.2.3.4:3000"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, can't get 8000 port:

```
curl -i -X GET \
  --url http://1.2.3.4:8000/
  --header 'Host: 1.2.3.4'

404 page not found
```

`1.2.3.4` is the fake IP address.

From [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/konglayer/ZEooisy6uE0) got should use either `request_host` or `request_path`. But there isn't either of them in this case.

It's the newest version. What's wrong?

Comment: I don't see you configuring `8000`? But `8001`?